# knockoutjs custombindings update method is not called

Tags: knockout.js

**update** I have moved the code to jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TnSV6/13/

when `edit` is called the model is set to a view model and the dialog is opened. however when `save` or `undo` is called the modal is set to null but the dialog does not close.

i can make this work if I explicitly use jquery in the jqDialog handler to make the cancel link and ajax complete event close the dialog box, but that feels a bit hackish because `jqDialog.update` should manage open/close.

it would seem a call is not begin forwarded to `jqDialog.update()`. but I'm not sure where that is being prevented.

Comment: Might help to get this going in a jsFiddle.  I would be interested in the area around the element with your `jqDialog` binding.  `$data` would typically already be unwrapped, so your `update` function is not actually getting a dependency on your observable, so it is not getting triggered.

Comment: @RPNiemeyer see the udpate for a link to the live example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what I said above is actually the issue.  Inside of your `with` the observable has already been unwrapped, so you are just dealing with the contents of `SettingShipmentDate.workOrder`.  The custom binding does not know about the actual observable that holds it.

An easy fix would be just to write it like:

```
<!-- ko with: SettingShipmentDate.workOrder -->
<div data-bind="jqDialog: $parent.SettingShipmentDate.workOrder, dialogOptions: {close: $root.SettingShipmentDate.undo}" data-title="Set Shipment Date">
```

Now your binding is passed the observable `workOrder` rather than just its contents and the unwrapping that you do in the binding's `update` function will be able to create the dependency.

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Y4JbP/

Otherwise, you could refactor it a bit to move the `with` statement onto the `div` or inside of it.  Although, the `with` is currently protecting against the value being null.

Comment: this fixes one problem, but introduces another. if you click a button the first time it works, but the second time will open multiple dialogs. I can't explain why though. Also the whole syntax feels verbose. I'm starting to consider if my approach is not flawed and I need to rethink edit bindings.

Comment: jQuery UI dialog moves the div hosting the dialog to the bottom of the page, so when Knockout re-renders the `with` area, it does not remove the dialog's div, so the disposal code is not triggered.  Here is an approach that handles this issue by disposing the dialog on close: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Dj32g/

Comment: wow, I would have never thought the jQuery DOM manipulation would distort the KO bindings.